# Unix script not working

Tags: bash

I have a script where I am checking for file name in the error folder then exit with 1. It is working in testing but not in production. What could have caused the difference:

```
if [ $exit_code -ne 0 ] || [ -s $error_path ]; then
    echo "Batch Job $1 aborted for file $(basename $i)"
    exit_val=1
else
    echo "Batch job $1 successfully completed for file $(basename $i)"
fi
```

Even though the file exists in the error path, it is moving to else statement. But it is working in testing.

Comment: is the size of the file is greater than zero? can u try with `-f` instead of `-s`...

Comment: Try double-quoting `"$exit_code"` and `"$error_path"`.

Comment: And maybe run the script with `bash -x` so you can see what `$error_path` is holding.  Maybe it has an unexpected value...

Comment: Please explain what `$error_path` and `$i` are and what you are trying to check. It sound like `$error_path` is a directory and you want to check for a file (`$i`?), but I don't know. The `-s` tests for a non-empty file. Do you want to test that? Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/542816/edit) your question to clarify.

Comment: what is the difference between the testing and production environments?

Comment: $error_path retrives complete file name along with path. as below + '[' -s /batch/app/fixfile/error/TAXRQST_20190828_D_5.txt ']'

Comment: this scripts run from third party tool which used sh -x

Comment: $i is file name

Comment: what -f does , this file is not empty file, it has data. Only difference i am seeing between prod and test is BASH_FUNC_module()=() {  eval `/usr/bin/modulecmd bash $*`
}